# Get Sinatra request route/path

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Is there a way that I can get the request route in Sinatra. For example, I have a route:

```
get "/:id/post" do
  # whatever
end
```

When I hit that endpoint, for example, "/abc/post", I want to log the route: `"/:id/post"`, instead of `"/abc/post"`, which I can get via `request.path_info`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The router [stores the matched route in `@env["sinatra.route"]`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/23c243d/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L988), so you can do this:

```
get '/:id/post' do
  logger.info "Route: #{@env["sinatra.route"]}"
  # ...
end
```

This will log:

```
I, [2016-12-05T10:59:36.678467 #35615]  INFO -- : Route: GET /:id/post
```